# I installed MariaDB 11.0 and there is no mysqldump.exe, any symlinks or any other program with 'dump' in its name

Tags: mariadb

I have a script that I can not modify and that relies on mysqldump.exe

I am using Windows 10. What can I use instead? I need to export a database into a file.

Comment: Which sub-version of 11.0?  Is it GA?  Or still a pre-release?

Comment: I installed 11.0.3, with default settings, and mysqldump.exe is there. mariabackup.exe is not there, but this is another story https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-32252

Answer (score 3):

[image]

It is there, in 11.0.3 . All install options are default.

Comment: Ok, thanks I will reinstall and check again. Good to know it is there,

Answer (score 1):

Search for 'mariadb' and 'mysqldump'.  It gets you to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqldump/, which says

> MariaDB starting with 11.0.1
> From MariaDB 11.0.1, mysqldump (the symlink) is deprecated and removed from the mariadb Docker Official Image. Use mariadb-dump instead.

Comment: I saw this page, that's why I made this post. That resource is unclear. I installed Maridadb and didn't omit any options, AFAIK. I have only these binaries, which one do you recommend using? `aria_dump_log.exe` `aria_ftdump.exe` `myisam_ftdump.exe` `sst_dump.exe`

Comment: Did you try using mariadb-dump? If you did, and it doesnt exist, did you try to search for dowloading it?

Comment: @RohitGupta there is no such program in my  PATH nor in my system. How do I download it? When I google its name, I see the page you showed me.

Comment: There are no whatever symlinks in Windows packages.